# Joomla site : baseurl does not return correct url

Tags: php, url, joomla, include

I use Joomla 2.5.7 and I get a problem with **$this->baseurl** in one page.

In my index.php file, I unclude .js files and .css files with **baseurl** like in this example :

```
        <script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And it works fine in this kind of page :

> http://mywebsite.com/index.php/myfolder

The page "myfolder" is a list of articles from on category.

And when I click on a article in this page, Joomla use this url :

> http://mywebsite.com/index.php/myfolder/article1

And here, all is incorrect (css, js, ...) because my **baseurl** returns this :

> /folder

instead of :

> /

And my includes in index.php are not good for this page !

Did you already met this issue ?

How to fix it ?

I didn't find where **baseurl** is defined, to correct it, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks for answers but I don't think you clearly understood that I had the problem only with url containing folder.

I found a solution by using **live_site** variable in configuration.php.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JURI::root()` to get the base root of Joomla

See Joomla Doc page [here](http://docs.joomla.org/JURI/root) for further information on it. Also [this](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=230710) Joomla forum post - whilst referring to a early RC of Joomla 1.6 might help a bit as well.

Comment: Should be JURI::root() not JRUI!! Sorry!

Comment: Oups, sorry for mistake. But I get same problem, it returns : **http://mywebsite.com/folder/** instead of **http://mywebsite.com/**

Answer (score 0):

First you build **this function** at the top of your script

```
function thisSite($a){
$this_raw = parse_url($a);
$b = preg_replace('#^www\.(.+\.)#i', '$1', $this_raw['host']);
return $b; }
```

Then you use **the function** this way

```
$thisSite = JURI::root();
// $thisSite will echo http://www.mywebsite.com/
$thisSite_base = thisSite($thisSite);
// the function removes http:// and the www and the /path
echo $thisSite_base;
```

**This will echo**

mywebsite.com

Answer (score 0):

In a template you can use the shortcut `$this->baseurl` instead of `JURI::base( true )`.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested these, but perhaps try one of them:

```
 JDocument::base
 JDocument::baseurl
 JURI::base()
```

Comment: I get same problem, it returns : **http://mywebsite.com/folder/** instead of **http://mywebsite.com/**